# grails backward compatibility

Tags: grails, web, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I recently get to know grails and start to using it, I know that grails is a great language and it is very helpful for rapid development, but I cant understand why grails dont have a good backward compatibility, I use grails 2.3.8 and grails 2.4 for my projects but many of sample codes in the internet are 2.2 or less, and it isn't time efficient to convert them to 2.3.8 or 2.4 because there are many changes from one version to another. And some times although I do any things right and every thing must work like it works with grails 2.1 or 2.2 but some things still remains.

Am I wrong? I skipped some things that make converting version so hard?

And above all this, what are the guaranties that projects I'm developing right now will be compatible with higher versions of grails that comes in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joshua Moore is right with his answer, but I do not see it as passimistic as he does.

The grails development team is brave enough to make changes which break with the past. I consider this as a great feature - Grails does not ride dead horses.

For me, most of the changes don't seem to bee too radical. Most of the time, I skip 2-3 version and then upgrade my apps to the current stable version in less than a day. This also helps me to get to know the new features.

If you don't know how to upgrade, the safest way is to use the `grails upgrade` command. Just increase you version number step by step and do an upgrade and re-run your test (yes, tests help you in your upgrade process :-). If tests fail, take a look at the great changelogs and the "What new in Grails x.y?" sections of the documentation.

Often it is also helpful to compare your old grails version app with a new and empty target version project with a good comparison tool like BeyondCompare. This way you easily spot changed configurations.

Hope that helps

**Update:** When you are new to "all those webconcepts" you should first decide on the platform you want to work on. If it is the java ecosystem, Grails is the best webframework on the market :-) Otherwise PHP, Rails, DJango etc. could also be a match.

So if you want to learn Grails (and with Grails all those webconcepts), I would suggest to start reading the [Guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html) which will tell you how Grails works. If you need more examples, I can suggest the "The Definitive Guide to Grails 2" published by Apress. It covers basically the same content as the guide, but it does so by walking you through a process of building a sample application.

When it comes to the samples you find on the net... as soon as you get to know the framework better, you will probaply know ho to handle the examples - but there is no silver bullet...

Comment: Thanks for your reply ralf, you said "I skip 2-3 version and then upgrade my apps to the current stable version in less than a day." I know one day is acceptable amount of time to upgrade an application, but there is one problem, I'm new in whole web concepts, I mostly done backend programming, so thing like backbone or angular and ... are new for me and I need to read about them and some times download their sample codes, and I think just for learning something else grials not time efficient.

Comment: Thanks again :) I'm a java programmer and for that I choose grails for the same reason that you said, but it updates really makes me crazy. I'll read the book that you suggested.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the updates. If you start now with grails, start with version 2.3.9 and stick to it. As Joshua already said, even the 1.3.x branch is still great...

Answer (score 2):

Nothing guaranties that your projects will be compatible with future versions of Grails. In fact, from my own experience, they won't. Often things change, and sometimes radically too, as Grails matures into higher versions.

The same holds true of backwards compatibility as well.

All you need do is take a look at the [introduction section](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0/guide/introduction.html) of the Grails documentation to see how often things change significantly between versions. A lot of times these changes require significant refactoring of older projects to upgrade them. I still have several large projects running on the 1.3.x branch of Grails because we don't have the resources (time) to go through and upgrade them.

Often this upgrade process involves creating a new empty project then slowly moving the code from the old project into the new project, updating code to reflect newer means of doing the same thing and testing. It's not easy for projects where you have 100+ Domain classes, 1000+ GSPs, 50+ Services and several hundred thousand lines of tests.